# Django ORM: how to make multi-conditional filter on related field?

Tags: django, django-orm

For example we have these models:

- Order (name, ...)
- Product(order, name, a, b, c)

And I want to exclude orders where all products satisfy condition `(p.a > 0 or p.b > 0) and p.c == 0`.

What I have tried so far:

```
Order.objects.all().exclude(
    Q(products__a__gt=0)
    | Q(products__b__gt=0),
    products__c=0,
)
```

But this query will filter out orders if any of related products satisfy the condition.

Solved this by swtiching logic from ALL to ANY:

```
Order.objects.filter(user=user).filter(
    Q(products__c__gt=0)
    | Q(products__a=0, products__b=0)
)
```

Comment: it's `gt` - "greater then", not `qt` (QT)

Comment: tnx, corrected that error. But I still have improper query.

Comment: @Aiven can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I don't have any error now, only bad query logic

Comment: What do you mean by that? Returned rows are not what you are expecting?

Comment: yes (>12 more chars to post comment<)

Comment: Turn it around: "True if all products satisfy condition C" is the same as "False if any product satisfies !C"